# How to demodulate an overmodulated signal?

Tags: modulation

[image]

Say I have an overmodulated signal like the example above. When you demodulate this you will get distortion. Is it possible to somehow demodulate this?

Comment: If you can recover the carrier and detect the phase flips, it should be possible.

Comment: A synchronous (or product) detector should be used. Widely used in SSB/CW receivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This signal is half way between regular AM modulation (for broadcasting music) and full double-sideband-suppressed-carrier. Because there is still carrier present you can filter this out to give a constant amplitude sine wave at only the carrier frequency. Use this sine wave and the original "over-modulated" signal and feed them into a balanced modulator (aka 4-quadrant multiplier) to recover the base-band audio.